# "Signed" email in PHP

Tags: php, email, encryption, cryptography

How would one "sign" an outgoing email using PHP?

The proper header I am looking at is:

```
signed-by   mydomain.com
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want. You don't just want the signed-by header - you want Domain Keys or something like this, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to generate a signed e-mail using PHP.

The standard way to send signed e-mails is S/MIME (another less common way is PGP). S/MIME is basically a MIME message containing the base64-encoding of a CMS message (CMS is also sometimes called PKCS#7).

One way to do this from PHP is with the PHP-bindings to OpenSSL's [`openssl_pkcs7_sign`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php).

I have no idea what the signed-by header should be used for.

Comment: that's why you need these headers: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .p12 file then you likely need to extract the public cert and private key from it:

Private Key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <YOUR_FILE>.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

Public Cert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <YOUR_FILE>.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pem
```

Then you can send a signed email with this PHP code:

```
<?php

$data = "This is a test signed email";

// create a temporary file
$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);


// sign the email
openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt", "signed.txt",
    file_get_contents(realpath("publicCert.pem")),
    array(file_get_contents(realpath("privateKey.pem")), '<YOUR_PASS>'),
    array(
        "To" => "john@example.com",
        "From: Jane Doe <jane@example.com>",
        "Subject" => "This is a test"
        )
    );



exec(ini_get("sendmail_path") . " < signed.txt");
```